# jQuery - Slide out sidebar

Tags: jquery

I found this code for a slide in/out sidebar. How to let it slide in after the website is loaded so people can sneak peak the content a bit?

(function sidebar() {

```
        var sidebar = $('#sidebar').show(),
            sidebarButton = $('#sidebarButton', sidebar),
            w = sidebar.outerWidth();

        sidebar.css('left', '-' + w + 'px');

        sidebarButton.toggle (

            function() {
                sidebar.css('left', 0).show('slide', { easing: 'easeOutCubic' }, 1000, function() {
                    sidebarButton.css('right', '-20px');
                });
            },

            function() {
                sidebar.animate({ left: '-' + w + 'px' }, 1000, 'easeOutCubic');
                sidebarButton.css('right', '-20px');
            }

        );



    }());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">My sidebar</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    toggle_sidebar();
    setTimeout(toggle_sidebar,3000);
});

function toggle_sidebar(){
    $('#sidebar').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zrdC4/

** *Requires JQueryUI*

Comment: Sorry it's me again with a follow up question. Is it possible to call the *(function sidebar() {* (I posted before) without a button?

Comment: Sure you can, but keep in mind `(function sidebar(){}()) is a [self-executing function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript), meaning all variables defined inside it are limited to that scope AND it will execute immediately by itself, so keep that in mind :)

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new to jQuery. What I'ld like to achieve is to call the function by multiple links and not just by the *sidebarButton*. I tried to use to call the function with *sidebar()* but than nothing happens. This is the code: http://pastebin.com/8ueMZSwx

Comment: In the example code I provided, you'd simply need to call `toggle_sidebar();` inside a click listener. For example if you have `<a class="sidebar_toggler">Show/hide sidebar</a>` you'd setup the listener like this: `$('.sidebar_toggler').click(function(event){event.preventDefault(); toggle_sidebar();});`

Comment: Great, thanks. I tried to edit your jsfiddle myself but without a satisficing result. So it would be very nice if you could answer me this 2 questions also. #1 How to make the slider stop 20px before the left screen border so it keeps beeing visible?  #2 How to start the "onload" toogle directly from the "slide out status" so it's just a "slide in" and not a "slide out + slide in"?

Comment: @AlienWebguy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2196/discussion-between-michael-and-alienwebguy)